# AWS Security Token Service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, credentials

Using AWS STS, we have a service A that requests temp credentials to access an S3 bucket and we want to use the same temp cred by another service B. Is there a way to retrieve them? pass those credentials when making a request to S3?
*Service B has not access to S3.

Comment: The correct solution is to grant access to service B. Why can't you do that?

Comment: we don't want service B to be permanently trusted and thus be able to read from S3 unless it can get temp credentials from a service that is fully trusted.

Comment: Use the Assume Role operation exposed by the AWS Security Token Service

Comment: What language are you using? If you show your code that retrieves temporary credentials, and it's in  a language that I use, I will show you how to extract those credentials, as well as scale-down access to a single object. If it's not a language that I use, someone else will have to answer.